# How can I get composer to show just the name of the current project?

Tags: php, shell, composer-php

Is it possible to get just the name of the current project? I want something like:
`composer show --self --name-only`

#### 1. Show current project

`composer show --self`

#### 2. Show name of all packages

`composer show --name-only`

Comment: **Mod note:** Self answers are acceptable and encouraged on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Composer version 2.2.4, you can use

```sh
$ composer show -s --name-only
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with some shell mess, but it's not ideal.

`composer show -s | grep 'name' | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'`